# Oracle Query for Update And Return Updated Rows

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm developing an Oracle table for the purposes of distributed messages. I have a table as follows:

```
TABLE messages
messageid    VARCHAR(15)
pulltime     DATETIME
attempt      NUMBER(100)
```

When a message consumer queries for a message, I want to update the pulltime by attempt * hours and increment the attempt number:

```
UPDATE messages
    SET pulltime = SYSDATE + attempt / 24, attempt = attempt + 1
    WHERE pulltime < SYSDATE;
```

At the same time, whatever is updated, I also want to query it and return the rows to my application, to process the messages. Since there are multiple consumers, I want to be able to update the messages ready to be processed, and update their pulltime to lock other consumers from consuming the same message until the next pulltime in one operation (if the message is successfully consumed, we will remove the entry from the table with a separate command).

EDIT: The consuming application will be a Java application and I want all the columns returned (messageid, pulltime, and attempt).

Comment: How does the consume query for a message? Is this inside pl/sql function or procedure?

Comment: It'll be through a Java application.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in **PL/SQL** using:

- **FOR UPDATE** clause - will lock the rows from other sessions to update
- **RETURNING INTO** clause - will return the rows being updated

For example, using standard EMP table in SCOTT schema:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_empno NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4    FOR i IN
  5    (SELECT * FROM emp WHERE deptno = 10 FOR UPDATE
  6    )
  7    LOOP
  8      UPDATE emp SET deptno = 99 WHERE empno = i.empno RETURNING empno INTO v_empno;
  9      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('updated empno is = '||v_empno);
 10    END LOOP;
 11  END;
 12  /
updated empno is = 7782
updated empno is = 7839
updated empno is = 7934

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: should you add commit to release the lock ?

Comment: @Moudiz Yes of course. Or, use `SKIP LOCKED` to skip the already locked rows and not wait. i left that portion up to OP as I have mentioned that FOR UPDATE would lock the rows. And quite obviously COMMIT would be done by the calling environment.

Comment: I tried running the above command and the result returns 0 records.

Comment: @VerticalEvent Then show us what you did like I have demonstrated.

Comment: I ran your code through Mybatis in Spring and recreated your tables. It updated all the record with the new values but it found 0 records during the selection process. As far as I can tell, this only outputs the updated record keys to the screen, and does not return anything usable to a application external to the Oracle database.

Comment: @VerticalEvent Isn't it quite obvious that you need a procedure with an OUT parameter to give the returning value as output from database to Java?